# Calculating maximum float value

Tags: loops, math, floating-point, precision

I want to calculate maximum float value (lets say f64) iteratively. I was thinking of multiplying some number like 1.0 times 2 until it reaches infinity, but it won't give me an exact number. Something like adding macheps won't work neither because it's too slow. I am sure you have to increase/decrease divisor/multiplier by something each time you reach infinity, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: To devise a correct algorithm for computing the largest floating-point number (aside from `Inf`), you would need to know about how floating-point numbers are implemented; however, that knowledge should be enough for you to lead you to the answer without any computation. So what's the point?

Comment: The point is that it is an exercise and it took me long enough to make me curious how to actually do it.

Comment: You did not specify a programming language. For example, if you use a standard-compliant C compiler, and the compiler supports IEEE-754 semantics (this may require a compiler flag such as `/fp:strict`), you could use: `printf ("largest magnitude:  %23.16e\n", nextafter (exp(1e10), 0.0));` which prints `1.7976931348623157e+308` on my machine. `exp(1e10)` evaluates to infinity, and `nextafter()` produces the largest normal as the next smaller representable quantity.

Comment: Even without using `nextafter`, if your problem is that the result becomes `+inf` after a while, nothing prevents you from restarting from the value you had before the `+inf` and multiply by `1.1` this time instead of `2.0`. When that reaches infinity, restart from the last finite number and multiply by `1.01` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your programming language’s standard library should give you a constant representing the numeric limits of your types.  If you want to try a loop, though: you should carefully read the documentation for errors (including loss-of-precision and overflow) and remember that the largest representable number is not merely the largest exponent, but the largest exponent multiplied by the largest mantissa.

That said, computing the powers of 2 until you get an error, then adding them from greatest to least until you get an error, should work.

Comment: Well adding each of them once won't really work.. so a nested loop I guess but it will take a long time I suppose

Comment: What do you get in a *n*-bit type when you add 2^(n-1)+2^(n-2)+…+2^0? Floating-point numbers are stored with the equivalent of scientific notation, but the principle of 2^n(2^0 + 2^-1 + … + 2^-n) is the same. The biggest problem is if your FP library gives 2^(n-1) some special meaning.